# React-native-calendars Show previous and next month instead of arrows using renderArrow function

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

**Description**
Show previous and next month instead of arrows using renderArrow function

**Expected Behavior**
Show previous month at left side and next month at right side

**Observed Behavior**
Both side shows previous month

My Code:

```
<Calendar
onDayPress={(day) => {this.setDay(day)}}
renderArrow={(left,right) => (left? {this.state.previousMonth}: {this.state.nextMonth})}
pastScrollRange={0}
markedDates={{[this.state.selected]: {selected: true, disableTouchEvent: true, selectedColor: '#C7A985'}}}
firstDay={1}
theme={{
selectedDayTextColor: 'white'
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things to **note** in your **code**.

- The renderArrow function contains `direction` as a parameter which
  subsequently contains the values `left` and `right`
- The renderArrow function accepts JSX attributes
  Therefore you need to modify your `code` in this way

  ```
   <Calendar
      onDayPress={(day) => {this.setDay(day)}}
      renderArrow={this._renderArrow}
      pastScrollRange={0}
      markedDates={{[this.state.selected]: {selected: true, disableTouchEvent: true, selectedColor: '#C7A985'}}}
      firstDay={1}
      theme={{
          selectedDayTextColor: 'white'
      }}
  />
  ```

and the function as

```
 _renderArrow = (direction) => {
        if(direction === 'left') {
            return <Text>{this.state.previousMonth}</Text>
        } else {
            return <Text>{this.state.nextMonth}</Text>
        }
    }
```